# debian wireless driver is not recognized

Tags: debian, wifi, dhcp

I've installed debian 9.7 recently and during installation i got this error:

> DHCP autoconfiguration failed

I continued the installation and as it finished the wireless doesn't work.
I've tried several ways but no results.

**kernel version: 4.9.0-8-amd64 , Laptop: Lenovo z51-70**

and this is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b4] (rev 93)     
    subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8270]    
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: It is a Z51-70. The question is also lacking technical details, debugging and time effort. Please include the model/generation/year of that particular Z51-70.

Comment: @GAD3R on the documentation it says to reinsert `modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi`. do you know where should i insert it?

Comment: @GAD3R so its a command, but it says modprobe is not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the `firmware-iwlwifi` following the instructions described on the [official documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi#Installation):

> Add a "non-free" component to /etc/apt/sources.list, for example:
>
> ```
> deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
> ```
>
> Update the list of available packages and install the firmware-iwlwifi package:
>
> ```
> apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
> ```
>
> As the iwlwifi module is automatically loaded for supported devices, reinsert this module to access installed firmware:
>
> ```
> modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi
> ```